# Should there be a separate tag for webrtc-native?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Webrtc](http://www.webrtc.org) has two sides. One is [libjingle](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/), which is used by browsers and native apps. The other is [getUserMedia](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) which is the `javascript` lib that can be used in browsers that support `webrtc`.

Currently there is a tag webrtc. I'm working with peerconnection, for a native ios app, my collleague is working on the same app, but for android. What we are doing has basically nothing to do with the javascript part. I have no idea how to set up a connection using the javascript functions that webrtc provides, I do know how to do it in objective-c and java.

I think there is a pretty large distinction between these two parts of the webrtc standard. And most people will not need to use both.

Because there is such a large difference and most people will probably only need one part, is a separate tag for webrtc-native justified? The only downside I can think of is that the group of people following webrtc is still pretty small, so splitting the group in two leaves even less people following the webrtc tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i guess there should be since in the future it is a good prospect and many people might get into native development with webrtc.